# I want to use powershell to map a network hard disk on a remote machine

Tags: powershell, remote-access, windows-server-2012

I was thinking I could do something like this:

> psexec \\func2_web1 New-PSDrive -Name x -PSProvider FileSystem -Root
>   \\argento\drops -Persist

But that fails and comes back with this message:

> PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark
>   Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
>
> PsExec could not start New-PSDrive on func2_web1:

I have enabled PSRemoting on func2_web1 (and I can run other psexec commands against that machine just fine).

Does anyone know how I can map a hard disk on a remote machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`PSExec` is not short for "PowerShell exec", it's "process exec". You cannot execute an PowerShell cmdlet directly from it. To use PSExec to execute a PowerShell command remotely, you must do the following (untested, as I don't have `psexec`):

```
psexec \\func2_web1 powershell.exe -command -nologo "New-PSDrive -Name x -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\argento\drops -Persist"
```

Or, if you want to go the remoting route from within your local PowerShell session:

```
invoke-command -computername func2_web1 -scriptblock {New-PSDrive -Name x -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\argento\drops -Persist}
```

With the latter, you may have "double-hop" issues that need to be [resolved via CredSSP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2009/06/25/9803001.aspx).